# Can't return array as wanted

Tags: javascript, arrays

first time on StackExchange. I've got recently into programming and therefore I'm learning JavaScript. I'm trying to get an array of n size with a sort of random numbers so I could later try sorting and searching algorithms and check what is efficient.

I may be missing something really easy but was trying this yesterday I I'm still unable to understand where the error is. I get an empty array.

I'm using inquirer 0.12.0,

```
var inquirer = require('inquirer');

// CONSTRUCT ARRAY WITH n SIZE n OF RANDOM NUMBERS
var value;
var limit;

var  questionRandomSize = [{
  type: 'input',
  name: 'randomsize',
  message: 'Input number for maximum random number.',
  validate: function (limit) {
    if (limit > 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return 'Input a number if you want to continue.'
    }
  }
}];

var questionArraySize = [{
  type: 'input',
  name: 'arraysize',
  message: 'Input number for array size.',
  validate: function (value) {
    if (value > 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return 'Input a number if you want to continue.';
    }
  }
}];

var nArray = new Array();

function arrayI(value) {
  for (i = 0; i < value; i++) {
    nArray.push(randomSize(limit));
    arrayI(value);
  };
}

inquirer.prompt(questionRandomSize, function (limit) {
  function randomSize(limit) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * limit);
  }
  inquirer.prompt(questionArraySize, function (value) {
    arrayI(value);
    mainMenu();
  });
});

//MENU
function mainMenu() {
  if (nArray.lenght === value){
    console.log(nArray);
  } else {
    arrayI(value);
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: for one thing, there is a typo: `nArray.lenght` → should be `nArray.length`

Comment: Why do you use this old version of inquirer?

Comment: Used in a javascript challenge I made a while ago. That's why. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many mistakes in your code, I've created a working version here:

```
var inquirer = require('inquirer');

var questionRandomSize = [{
    type: 'input',
    name: 'randomsize',
    message: 'Input number for maximum random number.',
    validate: function (limit) {
        if (limit > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return 'Input a number if you want to continue.'
        }
    }
}];

var questionArraySize = [{
    type: 'input',
    name: 'arraysize',
    message: 'Input number for array size.',
    validate: function (value) {
        if (value > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return 'Input a number if you want to continue.';
        }
    }
}];

var nArray = [];

function arrayI(limit, size) {
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        nArray.push(randomSize(limit));
    }
}

function randomSize(limit) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * limit);
}

inquirer.prompt(questionRandomSize, function (limit) {
    inquirer.prompt(questionArraySize, function (size) {
        arrayI(limit.randomsize, size.arraysize);
        mainMenu();
    });
});

//MENU
function mainMenu() {
    console.log('array', nArray);
}
```

Example output:

```
? Input number for maximum random number. 2
? Input number for array size. 4
array [ 0, 1, 0, 1 ]
```

Some of the errors I fixed:

- You are assuming that the return value from `prompt` is the value entered by the user, but it is actually an object containing the value as a property
- Your `randomSize` function was in the scope of a callback function and thus not accessible to your `arrayI` function
- In your `arrayI` function you were calling the `arrayI` function recursively, which doesn't make any sense

Other notes:

- You should create arrays using `[]`, not `new Array()`
- Always make sure you define variables with `var`, `let` or `const`, even if it is just the `i` in a for-loop
- You are using an outdated version of `inquirer` (0.12.0); it's always a good idea to keep your node modules current; the latest version uses [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instead of callback functions, which makes it easier to deal with the asynchronous nature of getting user input

Comment: He's using inquirer 0.12.0. In this old version, inquirer.prompt accepted a callback as second parameter.

Comment: Ah, I see. @joão-faustino, should I update the code example to use the old inquirer, or is it feasible for you to use the current version?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. If you can update It I would really appreciate it. Just using this old version now because this was what I used in a challenge I made a while back. @PatrickHund

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Done, thanks for telling me cause quite new here, still figuring things out!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! It looks like you want to want to generate an array of specific size with random numbers with specified limit.

Your problem does not rely on `inquirer` library, remove this redundant code from the question.

For solution, try making a clear function that returns an array you want.

```
function make_array(size, limit){

    // Makes an empty array
    var a = [];

    // Does what's inside (size) times
    for(var i = 0; i < size; i++){

        // Generates a random number between 0 and (limit)
        // Pushes into the array.
        a.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (limit + 1)));

    }

    // Returns the array
    return a;

}
```

It's actually 4 lines. You can get an array of size `size` with numbers from `0` to `limit` by invoking `make_array(size, limit)`:

```
var size  = 10;
var limit = 100;
var array = make_array(size, limit);
```

Get `size` and `limit` any way you want. From an input field or a [prompt()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp).
Good luck!